# How to configure MSDTC on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: msdtc, com+

I have a COM+ component on a different server, but when I made an update to one these components then it stopped working. How to configure MSDTC?

From the application log:

***A caller has attempted to propagate a transaction to a remote system, but MSDTC network DTC access is currently disabled on machine 'NACHINE11'. Please review the MS DTC configuration settings.***

I tried this 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/fix-new-transaction-cannot-enlist-in-the-specified-transaction-coordinator-on-server-2003-sp2/

But it doesn't look so in Windows Server 2008 R2. Is it located somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows Server 2008 R2, you can enable DTC and DTC network access by installing the "Application Server" role and the related role services.

Comment: which ones to install?

Comment: The ones you need... in your case, you'll probably need COM+ network access and distributed transactions.

Comment: There is no Application Server roleavailable on Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition

Comment: Well, that's because it's... the web edition; which can only be used as a web server.

Answer (score 0):

The primary settings are configured under Admin Tools/Component Services..

From there, expand Component Services/My Computer/Distributed Transaction Coordinator/Local DTC and right click to show properties.

Specifically, compare the “security settings” tab as that determines who and what can access the DTC.

Comment: Everything in your answer is in the link the original poster added.